# How to add data from a textbox and database to a listbox at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a school project which needs a database in it. I want to be able to input a name, which should be saved to the database, as well as be shown in a listbox. The other names that are already in the database should also be shown. At this moment i can only see the names that are already in the database, but i can't add new people via the Textbox. Can someone help me out?

code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string naam = tb_naam.Text;
        string geslacht = tb_geslacht.Text;
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * 
   FROM Persoon", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable PersoonTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(PersoonTable);
            lb_gebruikers.DisplayMember = "Naam";

            lb_gebruikers.ValueMember = "Id";
            lb_gebruikers.DataSource = PersoonTable; 
        }


        Persoon nieuwpersoon = new Persoon(naam, geslacht);
        personen.Add(nieuwpersoon);

        if (lb_gebruikers.DataSource == personen)
        {

            lb_gebruikers.Text = "Naam: " + nieuwpersoon.Naam + "Geslacht: " 
     + nieuwpersoon.Geslacht;
        }



    }
```

Comment: You have just set the DataSource of the list to a DataTable. How this could be equal to an object _personen_? (A List of Person it seems) The if makes no sense

Comment: you just need to re fetch data from database after inserting new record and assign it to your ListBox or Combox,

Comment: @Steve 'personen' is the name of the list i'm using to list the different persons ('personen') in the listbox, but reading the comment this is probably not the smartest way to do so haha.